# How to recreate this holographic metal shader in shadergraph?

Tags: unity, shaders

I have been trying to recreate a shader made in blender (seen here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98715/defining-angle-of-reflection-for-glossy-texture-nodes-to-make-holographic-meta) in shadergraph URP. I thought I would be able to use the same structure and instead of using mapping nodes, use "Rotation About Axis" node. This did not produce a similar result at all.

How would I go about making this shader?

Comment: There's three somewhat different images posted at that link: the example texture referenced in the question & the Blender results shown in the two answers. Which one are you trying to recreate?

Comment: The answer provided by risingfall